# How could I protect serial console?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, console, serial

How can I protect serial console which if forwarded over RS232-Ethernet to WAN?
Is it possible? I was thinking about it, but I can't figure it out.
Is it possible to allow login through serial console only for specific user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `pam_succeed_if` to the `auth` part of PAM's `login` stack with a condition that allows only people within a certain group to log in, e.g. `user ingroup clogin`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you get to your RS232 interface after logging in with SSH (on a different server/firewall) first? I break out in a cold sweat when I hear about un-encrypted root or RS232 sessions :-)

Comment: This only works if you don't need to protect it from the people that can SSH in.

Comment: I have gained better understanding of the context of your question, I'm sorry I assumed you were a noob running unencrypted sessions :-)

Comment: Well, if nothing will help me, I will go your way, but currently I'm trying do it differently ...